# How to have selenium input a username and password stored in a password manager such as dashlane?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm working on automating tests for a website.
We connect to this website using account credentials (email and password) which are stored in a password manager (in this case dashlane, but I guess the question could be relevant to any password managers).
I'm using selenium in python to run my tests.

How can I have selenium retrieve the user names and password from the password manager to then use them to connect?

I've been checking various selenium and dashlane documentation, but did not find anything that would indicated this is even a possibility

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Without documentation it's going to be difficult to find the information and decrypt it.  Dashlane does appear to be open-source though, so you could use the same methods in the code.